# Functions handles in matlab

Tags: function, matlab, handles

i've a problem to understand this snippet of code

```
output=lsqnonlin(@(argn) fun(arg1,arg2,argn),X0);
```

My idea is that  lsqnonlin will call the argn->fun function recursively,but i'm not sure.
is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to say what `lsqnonlin` will do without the functions' code. However, there is nothing inherently recursive in the function call in your question.

The 1st argument to `lsqnonlin` is a function handle, and in the function call in your question, you pass an anonymous function handle:

```
@(argn) fun(arg1,arg2,argn)
```

Which is a function with one argument to be used by the function, `argn`, and two parameters (are pre-set arguments), `arg1` and `arg2`. `lsqnonlin` uses the function handle you pass it in order to calculate the function value in a specific point or vector of points.

You can read more about anonymous function handle here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html#f4-70133

Comment: For your reference: [lsqnonlin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html)